# java xml parser with emoji character

Tags: java, xml, parsing, emoji

The following code is used to parse an xml file. I noticed that the emoji char is not being parsed correctly. In the example, input has one emoji at the end(http://www.iemoji.com/view/emoji/693/people/revolving-hearts), the character is doubled in the output. Is this a known bug?

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class XmlTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {            
        DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        domFactory.setValidating(false);
        File file = new File("c:\\temp\\emoji.xml");

        try {
            DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse(file);

            NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("entry");
            Node node = nodes.item(0);
            NamedNodeMap map = ((Element)node).getAttributes();

            for (int i=0; i<map.getLength(); i++) {
                Node n = map.item(i);
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println(n.getNodeValue());

                char[] chars = n.getNodeValue().toCharArray();

                for (int j=0; j<chars.length; j++) {
                    System.out.print(chars[j] + ", " + (int)chars[j] + "  ");                   
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}
```

Here's the input emoji.xml:

```
<Attributes>
  <Map>
    <entry key="name" value="test"/>
  </Map>
</Attributes>
```

and output:

```
name
n, 110  a, 97  m, 109  e, 101  
test
?, 55357  ?, 56478  t, 116  e, 101  s, 115  t, 116  ?, 55357  ?, 56478  ?, 55357  ?, 56478
```

Answer (score 5):

I can reproduce the problem using JDK 1.7.

The cause for the problem seems to be a **bug** in the XML parser shipped with the JDK
(In this case it is Xerces, located in packages `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.*` in rt.jar)

The emoji characters are not in the Unicode BMP and are therefore represented as two chars (high and low surrogate). When the parser encounters these surrogates it treats them in a special way and checks if they are a valid XML character when converted to a supplemental character.

The buggy code is located in `XMLScanner.scanAttributeValue` in the following code section

```
           } else if (c != -1 && XMLChar.isHighSurrogate(c)) {
                if (scanSurrogates(fStringBuffer3)) {
                    stringBuffer.append(fStringBuffer3);
                    if (entityDepth == fEntityDepth && fNeedNonNormalizedValue) {
                        fStringBuffer2.append(fStringBuffer3);
                    }
```

The two chars for the emoji character are parsed into a buffer variable `fStringBuffer3` and then appended to the buffer for the attribute value. The problem now is that `fStringBuffer3` is not cleared. When parsing the second emoji character it still contains the old content and therefore the chars are appended twice.

If you try with an attribute value containing three or more emojis you clearly see how they accumulate.

Comment: Funny, I wrote that test code written in the first post, and passed it on to
one of our customers. I opened up a Service Request against the Oracle JVM for this issue. Oracle SR number: 3-11255842301
Oracle defect number: 21694036

Answer (score 1):

A few updates:  This issue has been fixed in the early access release version of Java 9 (build 9-ea+103-2016-01-27-183833.javare.4341.nc). It still exists in the latest build of Java 8 (build 1.8.0_72-b15). For some reason Oracle closed the bug that was opened due to my service request against Java 6/7/8 for this issue (as not reproducable). I'm trying to get them to re-open it.

Here is the exact same issue, opened against openjdk, they fixed it in openjdk 9:
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8062362

Comment: Apparently, this bug was fixed in Java 1.8.0_92:
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8141098

I can confirm that it does not occur any more with java 1.8.0_102

Comment: thanks to you all for this detective work, finally making progress on this.